# Java 2D Array Specific Move

Tags: java

I have made a class where a 6x10 2D array is generated to act as a board.

A random starting location is then generated in the constructor.I only want adjacent moves to be possible.

For example, if the random location has been generated as (2,3) then for example the user enters (1,2) it would be a valid move, but (6,1) would be an invalid move.

Then if the user enters say (1,2), they can then go to any adjacent cell from (1,2).

I have included the class below, and the adjacent method I tried to make to test it, but I'm a bit confused on how I am approaching this.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {

    public static final int ROWS = 6;
    public static final int COLUMNS = 10;
    public int[][] board;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.getBoard();
        t.makeMove(6,1);  //I want this to be an invalid move.
        t.getBoard();
        t.makeMove(1,2);  // this should be a valid move
        t.getBoard();

    }

    public Test()
    {
        board = new int[ROWS][COLUMNS];
        createRandomLocation();
    }

    public void createRandomLocation()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int x = rand.nextInt(6);
        int y = rand.nextInt(10);
        board[x][y] = 1;
    }



    public void makeMove(int x,int y){
    if (Math.abs(x-cur_x)==0 || Math.abs(y-cur_y)==0) {
        board[x][y] = 1;
    }

    public String getBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();

        return Arrays.deepToString(board);
    }



}
```

Adjacent:

```
/*public boolean isMoveAllowed(int [][] array,int x, int y){
            boolean adjacent = false;
            int trueCount = 0;
            if(array[x-1][y-1] == 0) trueCount++; //topleft
            if(array[x-1][y] == 0) trueCount++; //top
            if(array[x-1][y+1] == 0) trueCount++;//topright
            if(array[x][y+1] == 0) trueCount++;//right
            if(array[x][y-1] == 0) trueCount++;//left
            if(array[x+1][y-1] == 0) trueCount++;//bottomleft
            if(array[x+1][y] == 0) trueCount++;//bottom
            if(array[x+1][y+1] == 0) trueCount++; //bottomright

            if (trueCount == 8)
            {
                adjacent = true;
            }
            return adjacent;
        }*/
```

Comment: You should have a way to keep track of where you are in the grid, and then if the move isn't one up/down/right/left from the current position then return false

Answer (score 1):

Your problem description has the answer baked into it already. You want any move from (a,b) to (c,d) to be legal if the distance between a and c, and b and d, is zero or one. So if you see `Math.abs(a-c)>1`, that's an illegal move. So: have the current position stored in some variables, and compare them to the desired new location:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Board b = new Board(6, 10);
    try {
      b.tryMove(6,1);
    } catch(IllegalMoveException e) {
      // do whatever you need to do to inform the user that move is illegal
    }
}
```

With the Board class responsible for tracking coordinates:

```
class Board {
  protected int cur_x, cur_y, rows, cols;

  public Board(int rows, int cols) {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;
    this.setRandomPosition();
  }

  public void setRandomPosition() {
    cur_x = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * cols);
    cur_y = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * rows);
  }

  public void tryMove(int x, int y) throws IllegalMoveException {
    if (Math.abs(x-cur_x)>1 || Math.abs(y-cur_y)>1) {
      throw new IllegalMoveException(...);
    }
    // bounds check omitted here, but: ensure that
    // 0<=x<cols and 0<=y<rows, otherwise throw an
    // IllegalMoveException as well.
    cur_x = x;
    cur_y = y;
  }
  // with getters for the current x and y, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to test for a true case rather than a false case like you currently have, the isMoveAllowed method should look something like this:

```
public boolean isMoveAllowed(int[][] array, int x, int y) {
    return ((array[x + 1][y] == 1) || 
            (array[x - 1][y] == 1) || 
            (array[x][y + 1] == 1) || 
            (array[x][y - 1] == 1));
}
```

This will return true if the move is adjacent to the current player position